# Marked nodes in Fibonacci heaps

Tags: data-structures, heap

I don't understand why [Fibonacci heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) have marked nodes ([picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aFibonacci_heap.png)).
A node is marked when its child is deleted. Quoting from Wikipedia: "[Keeping degree of each node low] is achieved by the rule that we can cut at most one child of each non-root node. When a second child is cut, the node itself needs to be cut from its parent and becomes the root of a new tree."

Why do we need to do that? Why not just leave the node where it is after the second child is cut? The heap structure is not violated. I don't see the point of this optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is not that it would violate the heap invariant, but that it would lead to a state in which the heap would be inefficient.

The heap is efficient because after compaction there is only log(*N*) trees. To guarantee that you need to know that a tree with root degree *k* contains at least *O*(2<sup>*k*</sup>) nodes. But if you can cut nodes freely, you could cut all the second-level children and the tree would remain of degree *k*, but could get down to *k*+1 nodes.

This is prevented by tearing the tree apart and compacting it's parts again in next compaction step.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Makes perfect sense, thank you!